# Angular/Jasmine testing with deffered promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, deferred, angular-promise

I am testing a controller using a combination of angular and jasmine, and am not completely sure about using deffered promises.

This is my spec code.

```
describe('Controller Tests', function(){
    var scope, searchAPI;

    beforeEach(function(){
        var mockSearchAPI = {};
        module('myApp', function($provide){
            $provide.value('searchAPI', mockSearchAPI);
        });
    });

    inject(function($q){
        var testData = {"message":"hi"};
        mockSearchAPI.executeSearch = function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(testData);
            return defer.promise;
        };
    });

    beforeEach('Main Search Controller Tests', function(){

        function($controller, $rootScope, _searchAPI_){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            searchAPI = _searchAPI_;
            $controller('MainSearchCtrl', function(){
                $scope: scope,
                searchAPI: searchAPI
            });
            scope.$digest();
        }
    });

    it('should return a promise correctly', function(){
        var field = "testfield";
        var value = "testvalue";
        var pageNumber = 1;
        var promise = scope.processQueryByField(field, value, pageNumber);

        //THIS LINE IS GIVING ME '{}'
        alert(promise); 
    });

});
```

I am unsure why the line that I am "alerting" is giving me output of '{}'. Shouldn't it be the data struct that I defined as "testData" in the inject function? I am not sure what is going on here. I have tried numerous solutions.

My controller code is basically a wrapper for the service

```
$scope.processQueryByField = function(field, value, pageNumber){
    return searchAPI.executeSearch(field, value, pageNumber);
}
```

Shouldn't I just be receiving the value that I defined inside the injector code?

Comment: `searchAPI.executeSearch` returns a promise right? so ultimately `processQueryByField` also returns a promise not data correct? So what is the expectation you want to set? On more thing is you need to get hold of `$rootScope` and apply a digest after the function is called before setting the expecation.

Comment: I just want to make sure that my mock is being set up correctly (that is, returning a promise), and that I am able to make more complicated tests. What do you mean by getting ahold of $rootScope and applying a digest before setting the expectation?

Comment: `it('should invoke execute search', function(){
      spyOn(mockSearchAPI,'executeSearch');
      var field = "testfield";
      var value = "testvalue";
      var pageNumber = 1;
      scope.processQueryByField(field, value, pageNumber);
      expect(mockSearchAPI.executeSearch).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockSearchAPI.executeSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(field, value, pageNumber);
    });`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1wZ8Jx?p=preview

Comment: I will elaborate in my answer of what i meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what expectation you want to set with the promise object, You do not need to test if a promise is resolved, instead you need to test what happens to the data *when* a promise is resolved.

Example:-

Change your mock to simplify:-

```
inject(function($q){
    var testData = {"message":"hi"};
    mockSearchAPI.executeSearch = function(){
       return $q.when(testData);
    };
});
```

Just for a demo i have added one more method in your controller which resolved to a data:-

```
.controller('MainSearchCtrl', ['$scope','searchAPI', function ($scope, searchAPI) {
        //At this point placing this method on scope is useless
        $scope.processQueryByField = function(field, value, pageNumber){
           return searchAPI.executeSearch(field, value, pageNumber);
        }
        //This when invoked will update the searchResults in the model.
        $scope.populateData = function(){
          $scope.processQueryByField(1,1,1).then(function(data){
            $scope.searchResults = data;
          })
        }
    }]);
```

Expectation #1:- Test whether when the method is invoked the api method is getting invoked with the expected arguments.

```
   it('should invoke execute search', function(){
     //Set up a spy on your mock api method
      spyOn(mockSearchAPI,'executeSearch'); 
      var field = "testfield";
      var value = "testvalue";
      var pageNumber = 1;
      scope.processQueryByField(field, value, pageNumber); //invoke scope method with args
      //Test if the mock api method has been called
      expect(mockSearchAPI.executeSearch).toHaveBeenCalled();          
      //test if it has been called with expected arguments.
      expect(mockSearchAPI.executeSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(field, value, pageNumber); 
    });
```

Expectation #2:- Test whether data is populated properly when the promise is resolved.

```
it('should return a promise correctly', function(){
    var field = "testfield";
    var value = "testvalue";
    var pageNumber = 1;

    var promise = scope.processQueryByField(field, value, pageNumber);
    //This is a useless expectation
    expect(promise).toBeDefined();


    scope.populateData();
    $rootScope.$digest(); //<-- Apply digest cycle, so the promise is resolved
    expect(scope.searchResults).toBeDefined();
    expect(scope.searchResults.message).toEqual("hi");
});
```

**[Test Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BJsgYN?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure this will send me into the right direction.

Comment: @PSL + 1 for an extra effort. I'm really learning a lot from your answers. Thank you.

Comment: @PSL you should get used to it. I'm answering in "not so popular tags" often and sometimes I spend a half an hour or more on the answer which doesn't even become accepted since the OP just disappears. And there are no views, no upvotes. It is what it is here, but we always have good exercises and get experience - this is much more important than points.

Comment: @alecxe Yeah that's true, well said!! I get that feeling in angular and some other tags sometimes.. Funny thing in angular tag is that, sometimes i get more votes than it deserves for some really easy answers.. :D

Comment: @PSL, sorry? I thought I accepted your answer as correct. Is there anything else I could have done?